How to require passed delegate invocation before function exit?
Over years of game development, I've found a common pattern to follow is to hand a function a delegate that it must execute upon completion of whatever that function needs to do, like a callback function that aught to be invoked before a method exits.
I've also found that not calling a required callback can lead to bugs that are both difficult to recognize and identify.
After solving such a bug today, my colleague and I mused if there was a compiler-level way to enforce the invocation of a passed delegate. Similar to how out parameters throw compiler errors if they are not set before the function terminates.
What I'm looking for is a compile-time way to guarantee that a delegate will be invoked before a function exits. I could not find one while searching documentation, but I might not know the right words to search for. I'd be fine with a solution that involved decorators/attributes, or even Roslyn compiler solutions. This just seems like the kind of thing that C# would handle natively.
Finally, if C# doesn't have this, I would love examples from other languages which have keywords/patterns to guarantee method invocation.

Consider a custom IDisposable that is manually initialized with your callback at the beginning of a method and is just automatically (or manually) disposed at the end, where the disposal just calls the callback. While it still doesn't guarantee that the disposable is even built, writing a custom analyzer that follows all parameters, tracks ones with your custom attribute (to mark these callbacks) and finds if the custom disposable is built, should be doable with Roslyn.

@WiktorZychla this is interesting, but often I'll invoke the delegate in some cases but erroneously forget to invoke the exit delegate in other cases. It looks like your method would invoke the exit delegate in every case? If this is true, that's not really desirable because I don't want to double-call the delegate.

C# doesn't have a built-in warning for unused parameters, much less unused delegates specifically.
However, Visual Studio has IDE0060: Remove unused parameter through it's Code Analysis feature. The downside is that it's not just for delegates, it includes any unused method parameter. But if that's fine by you, you can configure it as producing an error (or just a warning) through the IDE options:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General > Avoid unused parameters = All methods, Error
The second downside with this solution is that "using" a delegate parameter is not the same as invocation. These cases (including branches) won't be caught:
// Would raise IDE0600, and that's correct
public void RunCallback(Callback callback) {
    
}

// Would *not* raise IDE0600, and that's incorrect (would raise unused variable, but that's a different warning)
public void RunCallback(Callback callback) {
    Callback temp = callback;
}

// Would *not* raise IDE0600, and that's incorrect (never called if false)
public void RunCallback(Callback callback) {
    if (new Random().Next(2) == 0) {
        callback(this);
    }
}

// Would *not* raise IDE0600, and that's correct (purposefully discarded)
public void RunCallback(Callback _) {

}

It might be possible to write a custom code analyzer for this, which would follow the logic of the "use-before-initialized" errors, but it's not something I've ever used before.

I appreciate this approach, but often the delegate is used in some cases, but not in others. I was hoping for a way to guarantee invocation before a function exited in every single case, much like how an out parameter throws errors if unset before exit.

Then your best bet is the custom code analyzer, I assume. Nothing really exists like this in C# since "not using a delegate" isn't exactly something that most people would consider to be warning-worthy.
